# PieDonut R - Customize the size of the rings

Tags: r, graph, pie-chart, donut-chart

I made the following Piedonut:

[image]

The problem is that the inner circle takes too much space. The text of each individual category is too small to read (and overlaps sometimes). How can I reduce the size of the first ring?
I assume this can be done by tweaking the custom code (see below). But I don't see where (not an experienced programmer).

```
PieDonutCustom <- function (data, mapping, start = getOption("PieDonut.start", 
                                                             0), addPieLabel = TRUE, addDonutLabel = TRUE, showRatioDonut = TRUE, 
                            showRatioPie = TRUE, ratioByGroup = TRUE, showRatioThreshold = getOption("PieDonut.showRatioThreshold", 
                                                                                                     0.02), labelposition = getOption("PieDonut.labelposition", 
                                                                                                                                      2), labelpositionThreshold = 0.1, r0 = getOption("PieDonut.r0", 
                                                                                                                                                                                       0.3), r1 = getOption("PieDonut.r1", 1), r2 = getOption("PieDonut.r2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1.2), explode = NULL, selected = NULL, explodePos = 0.1, 
                            color = "white", pieAlpha = 0.8, donutAlpha = 1, maxx = NULL, 
                            showPieName = TRUE, showDonutName = FALSE, title = NULL, 
                            pieLabelSize = 4, donutLabelSize = 3, titlesize = 5, explodePie = TRUE, 
                            explodeDonut = FALSE, use.label = TRUE, use.labels = TRUE, 
                            family = getOption("PieDonut.family", ""), palette_name="Dark2")
{
  (cols = colnames(data))
  if (use.labels) 
    data = moonBook::addLabelDf(data, mapping)
  count <- NULL
  if ("count" %in% names(mapping)) 
    count <- moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "count")
  count
  pies <- donuts <- NULL
  (pies = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "pies"))
  if (is.null(pies)) 
    (pies = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "pie"))
  if (is.null(pies)) 
    (pies = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "x"))
  (donuts = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "donuts"))
  if (is.null(donuts)) 
    (donuts = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "donut"))
  if (is.null(donuts)) 
    (donuts = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "y"))
  if (!is.null(count)) {
    df <- data %>% group_by(.data[[pies]]) %>% dplyr::summarize(Freq = sum(.data[[count]]))
    df
  }
  else {
    df = data.frame(table(data[[pies]]))
  }
  colnames(df)[1] = pies
  df$end = cumsum(df$Freq)
  df$start = dplyr::lag(df$end)
  df$start[1] = 0
  total = sum(df$Freq)
  df$start1 = df$start * 2 * pi/total
  df$end1 = df$end * 2 * pi/total
  df$start1 = df$start1 + start
  df$end1 = df$end1 + start
  df$focus = 0
  if (explodePie) 
    df$focus[explode] = explodePos
  df$mid = (df$start1 + df$end1)/2
  df$x = ifelse(df$focus == 0, 0, df$focus * sin(df$mid))
  df$y = ifelse(df$focus == 0, 0, df$focus * cos(df$mid))
  df$label = df[[pies]]
  df$ratio = df$Freq/sum(df$Freq)
  if (showRatioPie) {
    df$label = ifelse(df$ratio >= showRatioThreshold, paste0(df$label, 
                                                             "\n(", scales::percent(df$ratio), ")"), 
                      as.character(df$label))
  }
  df$labelx = (r0 + r1)/2 * sin(df$mid) + df$x
  df$labely = (r0 + r1)/2 * cos(df$mid) + df$y
  if (!is.factor(df[[pies]])) 
    df[[pies]] <- factor(df[[pies]])
  df
  mainCol = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(nrow(df), name=palette_name)
  df$radius = r1
  df$radius[df$focus != 0] = df$radius[df$focus != 0] + df$focus[df$focus != 
                                                                   0]
  df$hjust = ifelse((df$mid%%(2 * pi)) > pi, 1, 0)
  df$vjust = ifelse(((df$mid%%(2 * pi)) < (pi/2)) | (df$mid%%(2 * 
                                                                pi) > (pi * 3/2)), 0, 1)
  df$segx = df$radius * sin(df$mid)
  df$segy = df$radius * cos(df$mid)
  df$segxend = (df$radius + 0.05) * sin(df$mid)
  df$segyend = (df$radius + 0.05) * cos(df$mid)
  df
  if (!is.null(donuts)) {
    subColor = makeSubColor(mainCol, no = length(unique(data[[donuts]])))
    subColor
    data
    if (!is.null(count)) {
      df3 <- as.data.frame(data[c(donuts, pies, count)])
      colnames(df3) = c("donut", "pie", "Freq")
      df3
      df3 <- eval(parse(text = "complete(df3,donut,pie)"))
      df3$Freq[is.na(df3$Freq)] = 0
      if (!is.factor(df3[[1]])) 
        df3[[1]] = factor(df3[[1]])
      if (!is.factor(df3[[2]])) 
        df3[[2]] = factor(df3[[2]])
      df3 <- df3 %>% arrange(.data$pie, .data$donut)
      a <- df3 %>% spread(.data$pie, value = .data$Freq)
      a = as.data.frame(a)
      a
      rownames(a) = a[[1]]
      a = a[-1]
      a
      colnames(df3)[1:2] = c(donuts, pies)
    }
    else {
      df3 = data.frame(table(data[[donuts]], data[[pies]]), 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      colnames(df3)[1:2] = c(donuts, pies)
      a = table(data[[donuts]], data[[pies]])
      a
    }
    a
    df3
    df3$group = rep(colSums(a), each = nrow(a))
    df3$pie = rep(1:ncol(a), each = nrow(a))
    total = sum(df3$Freq)
    total
    df3$ratio1 = df3$Freq/total
    df3
    if (ratioByGroup) {
      df3$ratio = scales::percent(df3$Freq/df3$group)
    }
    else {
      df3$ratio <- scales::percent(df3$ratio1)
    }
    df3$end = cumsum(df3$Freq)
    df3
    df3$start = dplyr::lag(df3$end)
    df3$start[1] = 0
    df3$start1 = df3$start * 2 * pi/total
    df3$end1 = df3$end * 2 * pi/total
    df3$start1 = df3$start1 + start
    df3$end1 = df3$end1 + start
    df3$mid = (df3$start1 + df3$end1)/2
    df3$focus = 0
    if (!is.null(selected)) {
      df3$focus[selected] = explodePos
    }
    else if (!is.null(explode)) {
      selected = c()
      for (i in 1:length(explode)) {
        start = 1 + nrow(a) * (explode[i] - 1)
        selected = c(selected, start:(start + nrow(a) - 
                                        1))
      }
      selected
      df3$focus[selected] = explodePos
    }
    df3
    df3$x = 0
    df3$y = 0
    df
    if (!is.null(explode)) {
      explode
      for (i in 1:length(explode)) {
        xpos = df$focus[explode[i]] * sin(df$mid[explode[i]])
        ypos = df$focus[explode[i]] * cos(df$mid[explode[i]])
        df3$x[df3$pie == explode[i]] = xpos
        df3$y[df3$pie == explode[i]] = ypos
      }
    }
    df3$no = 1:nrow(df3)
    df3$label = df3[[donuts]]
    if (showRatioDonut) {
      if (max(nchar(levels(df3$label))) <= 2) 
        df3$label = paste0(df3$label, "(", df3$ratio, 
                           ")")
      else df3$label = paste0(df3$label, "\n(", df3$ratio, 
                              ")")
    }
    df3$label[df3$ratio1 == 0] = ""
    df3$label[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = ""
    df3$hjust = ifelse((df3$mid%%(2 * pi)) > pi, 1, 0)
    df3$vjust = ifelse(((df3$mid%%(2 * pi)) < (pi/2)) | (df3$mid%%(2 * 
                                                                     pi) > (pi * 3/2)), 0, 1)
    df3$no = factor(df3$no)
    df3
    labelposition
    if (labelposition > 0) {
      df3$radius = r2
      if (explodeDonut) 
        df3$radius[df3$focus != 0] = df3$radius[df3$focus != 
                                                  0] + df3$focus[df3$focus != 0]
      df3$segx = df3$radius * sin(df3$mid) + df3$x
      df3$segy = df3$radius * cos(df3$mid) + df3$y
      df3$segxend = (df3$radius + 0.05) * sin(df3$mid) + 
        df3$x
      df3$segyend = (df3$radius + 0.05) * cos(df3$mid) + 
        df3$y
      if (labelposition == 2) 
        df3$radius = (r1 + r2)/2
      df3$labelx = (df3$radius) * sin(df3$mid) + df3$x
      df3$labely = (df3$radius) * cos(df3$mid) + df3$y
    }
    else {
      df3$radius = (r1 + r2)/2
      if (explodeDonut) 
        df3$radius[df3$focus != 0] = df3$radius[df3$focus != 
                                                  0] + df3$focus[df3$focus != 0]
      df3$labelx = df3$radius * sin(df3$mid) + df3$x
      df3$labely = df3$radius * cos(df3$mid) + df3$y
    }
    df3$segx[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
    df3$segxend[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
    df3$segy[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
    df3$segyend[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
    if (labelposition == 0) {
      df3$segx[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
      df3$segxend[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
      df3$segy[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
      df3$segyend[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
    }
    df3
    del = which(df3$Freq == 0)
    del
    if (length(del) > 0) 
      subColor <- subColor[-del]
    subColor
  }
  p <- ggplot() + ggforce::theme_no_axes() + coord_fixed()
  if (is.null(maxx)) {
    r3 = r2 + 0.3
  }
  else {
    r3 = maxx
  }
  p1 <- p + ggforce::geom_arc_bar(aes_string(x0 = "x", y0 = "y", 
                                             r0 = as.character(r0), r = as.character(r1), start = "start1", 
                                             end = "end1", fill = pies), alpha = pieAlpha, color = color, 
                                  data = df) + transparent() + scale_fill_manual(values = mainCol) + 
    xlim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + ylim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + guides(fill = FALSE)
  if ((labelposition == 1) & (is.null(donuts))) {
    p1 <- p1 + geom_segment(aes_string(x = "segx", 
                                       y = "segy", xend = "segxend", yend = "segyend"), 
                            data = df) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "segxend", 
                                                              y = "segyend", label = "label", hjust = "hjust", 
                                                              vjust = "vjust"), size = pieLabelSize, data = df, 
                                                   family = family)
  }
  else if ((labelposition == 2) & (is.null(donuts))) {
    p1 <- p1 + geom_segment(aes_string(x = "segx", 
                                       y = "segy", xend = "segxend", yend = "segyend"), 
                            data = df[df$ratio < labelpositionThreshold, ]) + 
      geom_text(aes_string(x = "segxend", y = "segyend", 
                           label = "label", hjust = "hjust", 
                           vjust = "vjust"), size = pieLabelSize, 
                data = df[df$ratio < labelpositionThreshold, 
                ], family = family) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "labelx", 
                                                           y = "labely", label = "label"), size = pieLabelSize, 
                                                data = df[df$ratio >= labelpositionThreshold, ], 
                                                family = family)
  }
  else {
    p1 <- p1 + geom_text(aes_string(x = "labelx", y = "labely", 
                                    label = "label"), size = pieLabelSize, data = df, 
                         family = family)
  }
  if (showPieName) 
    p1 <- p1 + annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0, label = pies, 
                        size = titlesize, family = family)
  p1 <- p1 + theme(text = element_text(family = family))
  if (!is.null(donuts)) {
    if (explodeDonut) {
      p3 <- p + ggforce::geom_arc_bar(aes_string(x0 = "x", 
                                                 y0 = "y", r0 = as.character(r1), r = as.character(r2), 
                                                 start = "start1", end = "end1", fill = "no", 
                                                 explode = "focus"), alpha = donutAlpha, 
                                      color = color, data = df3)
    }
    else {
      p3 <- p + ggforce::geom_arc_bar(aes_string(x0 = "x", 
                                                 y0 = "y", r0 = as.character(r1), r = as.character(r2), 
                                                 start = "start1", end = "end1", fill = "no"), 
                                      alpha = donutAlpha, color = color, data = df3)
    }
    p3 <- p3 + transparent() + scale_fill_manual(values = subColor) + 
      xlim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + ylim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + guides(fill = FALSE)
    p3
    if (labelposition == 1) {
      p3 <- p3 + geom_segment(aes_string(x = "segx", 
                                         y = "segy", xend = "segxend", yend = "segyend"), 
                              data = df3) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "segxend", 
                                                                 y = "segyend", label = "label", hjust = "hjust", 
                                                                 vjust = "vjust"), size = donutLabelSize, 
                                                      data = df3, family = family)
    }
    else if (labelposition == 0) {
      p3 <- p3 + geom_text(aes_string(x = "labelx", 
                                      y = "labely", label = "label"), size = donutLabelSize, 
                           data = df3, family = family)
    }
    else {
      p3 <- p3 + geom_segment(aes_string(x = "segx", 
                                         y = "segy", xend = "segxend", yend = "segyend"), 
                              data = df3[df3$ratio1 < labelpositionThreshold, 
                              ]) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "segxend", 
                                                        y = "segyend", label = "label", hjust = "hjust", 
                                                        vjust = "vjust"), size = donutLabelSize, 
                                             data = df3[df3$ratio1 < labelpositionThreshold, 
                                             ], family = family) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "labelx", 
                                                                                        y = "labely", label = "label"), size = donutLabelSize, 
                                                                             data = df3[df3$ratio1 >= labelpositionThreshold, 
                                                                             ], family = family)
    }
    if (!is.null(title)) 
      p3 <- p3 + annotate("text", x = 0, y = r3, 
                          label = title, size = titlesize, family = family)
    else if (showDonutName) 
      p3 <- p3 + annotate("text", x = (-1) * r3, 
                          y = r3, label = donuts, hjust = 0, size = titlesize, 
                          family = family)
    p3 <- p3 + theme(text = element_text(family = family))
    grid::grid.newpage()
    print(p1, vp = grid::viewport(height = 1, width = 1))
    print(p3, vp = grid::viewport(height = 1, width = 1))
  }
  else {
    p1
  }
}
```

Next, I make the figure with the following script

```
library(RColorBrewer)


data <- read_xlsx("PieChart2.xlsx")
head(data)

data <- rename(data , c("NMBS"="Niveau1"))

tiff('Figure1-2.tiff', units="cm", width=20, height=20, res=350)
PieDonutCustom(PD, aes(`NMBS`, Niveau2, count=n), 
         r0=0, showPieName = F, r1=0.6, r2=0.8,
         showRatioThreshold = F, donutLabelSize = 2, labelposition=1, 
         ratioByGroup=FALSE, explode=c(1,2,3,4,5),
         maxx = 1.15,
         palette_name = "Blues"
)
dev.off()
```

I need to reduce the size of the first ring. Does anyone know how it can be achieved?
I tried adjusting code in the custom function but can't find the solution.

Comment: I believe your answer will be related to the r0, r1, and r2 values for the PieDonutCustom function. Try playing around with those and see what happens. See more info and examples here: https://cardiomoon.github.io/webr/reference/PieDonut.html

Comment: I tend to dislike pie charts as they are used in the wrong places, but _this_ is a good looking chart.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a minimal example that you could see about applying to your code. As I suspected, those proportions are largely controlled by those r_ arguments. It's largely taking from [here](https://cardiomoon.github.io/webr/reference/PieDonut.html). Play with those r_ values to see what results in the best proportions for you.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(webr)
library(dplyr)

# Change the following to be applicable to your data set
df <- base::as.data.frame(Titanic)

PD <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Class, Survived) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = sum(Freq))

# Making PD plot
webr::PieDonut(
  PD,
  ggplot2::aes(
    Class,
    Survived,
    count = n
  ),
  title = "Titanic: Survival by Class",
  r0 = 0, # Start of Pie
  r1 = 0.50, # End of Pie
  r2 = 1.00 # End of Donut
)
```

Comment: Thank you all! It turns out: that changing the size of the rings is not that difficult. I hoped the problem of overlapping labels would be solved but that is not the case. 
I made a new question focussed on specifically that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77318052/piedonut-r-overlapping-labels